# how to use google font in a Qwik application?

Tags: web-applications, google-fonts, qwikjs

I want to use a font from google-font in my newly created qwik project.

The steps I followed:

1. since qwik applications doesn't have a index.html like react, I imported selected font into global.css file.
2. tried to refer the font name on css's font-family property.

Expected result:
I should able to refer the imported google font anywhere in a css file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

import google font inside global.css

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rokkitt:wght@200;800&display=swap");
```

Next you can use `font-family: 'Rokkitt', serif;` anywhere inside your project.

Also qwik have `root.tsx` where you can put your scripts and styles in head or body according to your use cases.

If you need to apply any changes in html element you can use `entry.ssr.tsx` file

```js
import {
  renderToStream,
  type RenderToStreamOptions,
} from "@builder.io/qwik/server";
import { manifest } from "@qwik-client-manifest";
import Root from "./root";

export default function (opts: RenderToStreamOptions) {
  return renderToStream(<Root />, {
    manifest,
    ...opts,
    // Use container attributes to set attributes on the html tag.
    containerAttributes: {
      lang: "en-us", // <html lang="en-us">
      theme: "dark",  // <html theme="dark">
      ...opts.containerAttributes,
    },
  });
}
```

I have created a working examples for you and integrated google fonts

- Open codesandbox using https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/damp-wind-7mx64g
- Visit /demo/todolist
- google font added in todo heading